# handle authentication using login password and oauth with spring security

Tags: java, spring-security, vaadin

I'm using `socialauth` to handle `oauth` authentication. Also I have basic `login&password` authentication(not implemented. but service method exists).

```
public Map<String, String> oauthAuthentication(String source, String callback) throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    SocialAuthConfig config = new SocialAuthConfig();
    config.load("oauth_consumer.properties");

    SocialAuthManager socialAuthManager = new SocialAuthManager();
    socialAuthManager.setSocialAuthConfig(config);

    String url = socialAuthManager.getAuthenticationUrl(source, callback);

    map.put("url", url);
    map.put("token", socialAuthManager.getCurrentAuthProvider().getAccessGrant().getKey());

    return map;
}

public String loginPasswordAuthentication(String username, String password) {
    return null;
}
```

But how to add `spring security` here? What should I keep and where? What authentication information I should keep? I have context for it and it works fine (intercept request and redirect to login page).